# jconsole redirect output log to file

Tags: java, jconsole

How can I save jconsole output in log file ?

I tried adding logging.properties but it has been ignored:

```
jconsole.exe -Jjava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -debug
```

Or

```
jconsole.exe -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -debug
```

Currently I'm getting Jconsole Output window with minimum logs as:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory RMI client socket factory in stub!
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.checkStub(RMIConnector.java:1875)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:295)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:357)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:294)
sorting table against column=0 ascending=true
sorting table against column=0 ascending=true
sorting table against column=0 ascending=true
```

I have also option to suppress, but I don't want it

> Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? The option `--console` I know for `jvisualvm` only.

Comment: @suboptimal  Java 8, I was maybe confused with `jvisualvm` output to console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start `jvisualvm` and log into a file you might create a `logging.properties` file

```
.level= FINER
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = jvisualvm.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

and start `jvisualvm` as

```
    jvisualvm -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```

Comment: is there a reason of using jconsole over jvisualvm?

Comment: @user7294900 `jconsole` is part of the JDK, whereas from Java 9 onward `jvisualvm` is not part of the JDK anymore and you have to install `visualvm`. All other depends which feature you use.